# Drupal Views and Menu Block on a Multilingual Site

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-navigation

I have a **multilingual** site built on **Drupal 7.34**. I am using `Menu Block` module to show secondary level links on pages. The system is working except one condition. When I have a page built with `Views` module, menu block is only showing on one of the languages.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the problem is based on **Drupal Menus**. Wrong or missing `active-trail` classes on active links result in no `secondary link block`. After some research on *drupal.org*, it seems some patches are published to resolve this issue, some of them are said to work, I didn't try. Anyone who faces an issue like that can look on this forum page. https://www.drupal.org/node/942782